# Ionic Cropping Error

Tags: ionic-framework, crop

I'm trying to make a cropper for an app using ionic v1. I am following this:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/imageresizer/

I have changed up the format of the code so it follows ionic v1. Now, within the function where you click on a picture, my code looks like this:

```
    var options = {
        uri: './pic1.jpg',
        quality: 90,
        width: 1000,
        height: 1280
    };

    $cordovaImageResizer
    .resize(options)
    .then(function(image) {
    console.log('FilePath', image); },
    function() { 
        console.log('Error occured'); 
    });
```

When I do Ionic serve, it goes straight to 'Error occured' and when I try running it on my device using XCode, I get the following error:

2017-02-28 12:39:35.009885 cropApp[5906:1609632] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate:  *** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]

Does anyone know what the problem is and how I can solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. You must add the fileName parameter, required for iOS.

```
var options = {
    uri: './pic1.jpg',
    quality: 90,
    width: 1000,
    height: 1280,
    fileName: 'image.jpg'
};
```